# How can I send GET to flask with GET/POST

Tags: flask, http-post, jinja2, get-request, python-requests-html

In templates folder I have index.html and template.html
I'm trying to GET data from a form in index.html, process the data and POST the results in template.html as

.

index.html:

```
<form method="POST">
     <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="regions_brato">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  {% for each,key in new_dict.items() %}
  <option value="{{each}}">{{each}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

     <select name="list_status">
  {% for key in listStatus %}
    <option value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

template.html:

```
..
<body>
  {% for each,key in res.items() %}
  <p>{{each}}</p>
  {% endfor %}

</body>
..
```

Flask:

```
@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    listStatus = ['en', 'fr', 'bg']
    new_dict = {}

    with open('fr.json') as json_file:

        data = json.load(json_file)
        for each in data:
            new_dict.setdefault(each['admin'], []).append(each['city'])

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', listStatus=listStatus, default="en", new_dict=new_dict)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('template'))


@application.route('/template')
def template():
    region = request.form["regions_brato"]
    lang = request.form["list_status"]
    res = get_feel(region, lang, 30)
    return render_template("template.html", res=res)
```

Can anyone point me to where exactly I have messed up the GET/POST requests and any possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you messed up something, but I know you can't test posting without some help, it is not viewable. You need an app like Postman or a server. Maybe it is just that.

Comment: Im currently trying to run this project on a AWS EC2 instance. Despite everything I've tried, I'm still getting 500 Internal Error when doing a POST request..